# stopping refresh after liking a post : Django

Tags: javascript, django

Is there any way to stop refreshing a page after liking it or commenting on with in django platform without using ajax. I don't know about ajax i know little about Javascript only and i'm working on django. If there is any way please tell or just give me a link from where i can learn it

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't update a part of a page without using JavaScript/AJAX.

Comment: can i only use js not ajax?

Comment: No. AJAX is a (nebulous) term for doing a request without navigating to another page, which is exactly what you want here. Why would you want to do things without AJAX?

Comment: bcoz i don't know ajax and i say a guy in youtube doing it so i copy that code and it works but its counting properly [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61597981/counting-problem-in-django-blog-using-django-ajax/61599475#61599475) see that i posted it yesterday a guy replied but i don't know how to do tha

Comment: Right, well, I replied there with a couple suggestions.

Comment: thnk u so much n_n